# what does 그래서 누구냐고 무러본곤데 mean?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, translation, meaning, hangul

what does “ 그래서 누구냐고 무러본곤데” exactly mean in english? i tried translating it but it said “ Replying to @Fresh_Fresh“ in english which doesn’t make sense. please help me out!

Comment: The correct spelling is "그래서 누구냐고 물어본 건데." What is the context?

Comment: they basically dm’d me on instagram saying that

Comment: just block creepy dm'ers why try to analyze what they're saying

Answer (score 1):

that means "so that is why I asked who it was." someone may be asking "why are you asking who John is?" 존이 누구냐고 왜 물어봐? and the person responding will be like "Oh, I saw him on the street. So that is why I asked who it was."

Answer (score 1):

The right spelling of the question is “그래서 누구냐고 물어본 건데”. Which means “So I asked who are you?” Or “So that’s why I asked who is that person?”. The feeling of the one who asked would want to emphasize the question and want the answer as quick as possible. It’s because the sentence attached with “ㄴ 건데” which this grammar is used when speaker want to strongly stress/emphasize on something.